# Override Ionic swipe back gesture

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

By default ionic swipe back gesture works when you start swipe on the left side of the screen. I would like to extend the possible swipe zone to half of the screen. In ionic sources swipe back gesture is configured like this:

```
{
  direction: 'x',
  edge: 'start',
  maxEdgeStart: 75,
  threshold: 5,
  zone: false,
  domController: domCtrl,
  gesture: gestureCtlr.createGesture({
    name: GESTURE_GO_BACK_SWIPE,
    priority: GESTURE_PRIORITY_GO_BACK_SWIPE,
    disableScroll: true
  })
}
```

So I believe that what I need is to override maxEdgeStart value. Is there any way to change this defaults other than forking ionic, which I don't want to do?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @mpiz sort of, I had to tinker with ionic sources to achieve that. I didn't have to fork it, I'm using npm "postinstall" hook to overwrite "maxEdgeStart" . It's not a clean solution though, so I won't recommend doing it.